# No suitable Java Virtual Machine could be found on your system on Mac

Tags: java, macos, java-8, java-home, knowage

I'm trying to open "knowage.sh" with terminal on Mac, but I have this problem:

- No suitable Java Virtual Machine could be found on your system.
  The version of the JVM must be at least 1.8 and at most 1.8.
  Please define INSTALL4J_JAVA_HOME to point to a suitable JVM.

I have installed idk 1.8 and I set up JAVA_HOME.
How can I fix?

Comment: Looks like it's asking you to define INSTALL4J_JAVA_HOME to point the JVM, not JAVA_HOME.  I'd be wary of any system that was still stuck on JDK 8, which has reached the end of its support life, and using JAVA_HOME environment variables to find the JVM.

Comment: As suggested in previous comment , set INSTALL4J_JAVA_HOME to Java home path.  Alternatively edit knowage.sh and set the path for  INSTALL4J_JAVA_HOME

Answer (score 0):

Set INSTALL4J_JAVA_HOME on MAC like JAVA_HOME in .zshrc libe below

```
$  sudo ln -sfn /opt/homebrew/opt/openjdk/libexec/openjdk.jdk /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk.jdk

$  echo 'export PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/openjdk/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc

$  echo 'export PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/openjdk/libexec/openjdk.jdk/Contents/Home/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc

$  echo 'export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)' >> ~/.zshrc

$  echo 'export INSTALL4J_JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)' >> ~/.zshrc

$  source ~/.zshrc
```